# Changing the size of one element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function on Java Script that includes this line:

```
$(this).html(event.strftime('%T' + '<br>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp; TEXT &nbsp;&nbsp;'));
```

%T is a variable that returns me a number. I set the normal font size on my web-page to 20px so its shows the resulting number and the word "TEXT" in the same size, but I wants that the "TEXT" will be 10px for example, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: the JS is irrelevant. if you want some piece of a webpage to have a particular format, you need to add style rules to make that happen. that means spans/divs+css

Comment: @MarcB Yea I knows that I can do it with css or something, but I wonder if I could do it with JS only... so the answer is no?

Comment: doesn't matter how you do it. in the end, the html you're generating/inserting HAS to contain the structure/rules necessary to make your 10px font change happen.

Comment: @Roy The only way to specify the size of things is with CSS. You can use JS to add the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `<span>` tag with css rules (either inline or external, inline is shown):

```
this.innerHTML = event.strftime('%T' + '<br>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="font-size:10px">TEXT</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;');
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I asked here to see if I can do it with JS only? is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how to execute strftime in pure JS but I'll update to make it more non-jQuery

Comment: This is JS only solution. You can not change style without modifying the inline or external styles. You could use jquery css property but underneath it will also use style attribute.